# Partial results using speech recognition

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-2.3-gingerbread

I created a simple application inspired by [this example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html) in order to test all the available options (ie extra). I read about the [`EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS` extra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS) and if I enable this option I should receive from the server any partial results related to a speech recognition. However, when I add this extra to the `ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` intent, the voice recognition does not work anymore: the list does not display any results.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        switch(resultCode) {
        case RESULT_OK:
            Log.i(TAG, "RESULT_OK");
            processResults(data);
            break;
        case RESULT_CANCELED:
            Log.i(TAG, "RESULT_CANCELED");
            break;
        case RecognizerIntent.RESULT_AUDIO_ERROR:
            Log.i(TAG, "RESULT_AUDIO_ERROR");
            break;
        case RecognizerIntent.RESULT_CLIENT_ERROR:
            Log.i(TAG, "RESULT_CLIENT_ERROR");
            break;
        case RecognizerIntent.RESULT_NETWORK_ERROR:
            Log.i(TAG, "RESULT_NETWORK_ERROR");
            break;
        case RecognizerIntent.RESULT_NO_MATCH:
            Log.i(TAG, "RESULT_NO_MATCH");
            break;
        case RecognizerIntent.RESULT_SERVER_ERROR:
            Log.i(TAG, "RESULT_SERVER_ERROR");
            break;
        default:
            Log.i(TAG, "RESULT_UNKNOWN");
            break;
        }
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "Intent data: " + data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void processResults(Intent data) {
    Log.i(TAG, "processResults()");

    ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

    // list of results
    ListView listOfResults = (ListView)(findViewById(R.id.list_of_results));
    listOfResults.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, matches));

    // number of elements of above list
    TextView resultsCount = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.results_count));
    resultsCount.setText(getString(R.string.results_count_label) + ": " + matches.size());
}
```

When this option is enabled, the number of elements in the list of results is equal to 1 and this one result is an empty string. What is the reason for this behavior?

**ADDED DETAILS**
I used the following code in order to enable `EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS` option (on Android 2.3.5).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, ...);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, ...);
startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);   // where VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE is a "global variable"
```

However, enabling this option, the `ArrayList<String> matches` in `processResults` method has only one empty element.

Comment: What is inside of EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS?

Comment: A constant string value (`"android.speech.extra.PARTIAL_RESULTS"`) that can be used to enable or disable the "pratial results" option, so I set it with the boolean value `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest not relying on PARTIAL_RESULTS because the Google documentation says this:
[The server may ignore a request for partial results in some or all cases.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS)

In my experience, Google almost always ignores requests for partial results.

However, I don't believe that setting `EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS` should stop normal `EXTRA_RESULTS` from being returned. It should just have no effect. I have tested this in my code and adding `EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS` doesn't change the output.

Also, unless you are using `SpeechRecognizer`, Android won't send you those error codes.

To see that `EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS` does not interfere with the results. Get the code from [here](https://github.com/gmilette/Say-the-Magic-Word-) then add the extra within this method:

```
private void sendRecognizeIntent()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say the magic word");
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 100);
    startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Comment: I'd like to understand why my tests (with `EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS` option) on Android 2.3.5 do not work. What instructions did you use to request partial results? (I simply added this extra to the intent: see the details that I added at the end of my question). What instructions did you use to access the partial results? There should be returned together with complete results... or not?

Comment: Get the code from here: https://github.com/gmilette/Say-the-Magic-Word-

Then add intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);

Note: I tested on Android 4.0.3

Comment: Soon I'll try the code from your link! If the same problem will occur, what could be causing this? The version 2.3.5 of Android or the version of the speech recognizer (I have Voice Search 2.1.3)?

Comment: I just tried the code from your link on Android 2.3.5 with Voice Search 2.1.3 installed: when I add `intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);`, the list of the results is always empty. I suppose that this problem is caused by Voice Search application: I could try to update it with the last version!

Comment: Interesting quirky bug. By the way, It works on a Droid X, with Android version 2.3.3, voice search 2.1.4

Comment: I have used Partial Results within my application and they worked fine. What I discovered is that onPartialResults gets called many times and the results array is never empty, it always has a size of 1, and the majority of times the entry is an empty string. Each none empty result gradually becomes more accurate.